# Does a sourced bash script contain wrong values for $BASH_SOURCE?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-expansion

[The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) says:

> When a file is sourced (by typing either source filename or . filename at the command line), the lines of code in the file are executed as if they were printed at the command line. This is particularly useful with complex prompts, to allow them to be stored in files and called up by sourcing the file they are in.

I have three scripts: `test.sh`, `test2.sh` and `common.sh`. `common.sh` sets up the variable `$me` containing the base name of the current script (using `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`). `test.sh` calls `source` on `common.sh` and displays `$me`. `test2.sh` calls `eval` on the contents of `common.sh` and displays `$me`.

```
==> common.sh <==
#!/bin/bash

realpath=$(realpath "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
me=$(basename "${realpath}")

==> test.sh <==
#!/bin/bash

source common.sh

echo "me: $me"

==> test2.sh <==
#!/bin/bash

common=$(cat common.sh)
eval "$common"

echo "me: $me"
```

When running `./test2.sh`, the output is `me: test2.sh`. This is correct.

When running `./test.sh`, the output is `me: common.sh`. **Why is this the case?**

**EDIT**

Jeff Schaller's answer is correct, in that `sourcing` another script "unshifts" the name of that script to the `$BASH_SOURCE` array. I was able to achieve what I wanted by looking at the *last* value in `$BASH_SOURCE`. See below:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -p BASH_SOURCE
bash_source_size="${#BASH_SOURCE[*]}"
realpath=$(realpath "${BASH_SOURCE[$bash_source_size-1]}")
me=$(basename "${realpath}")
```

Comment: Just `realpath=$(realpath "${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}")` should be enough if the name of the most external sourced file is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `test.sh` calls `source`, bash is explicitly sourcing `common.sh` into the current script, and so updates the `BASH_SOURCE` variable. When `test2.sh` executes the command substitution (which could be anything) and subsequent `eval`, there is no explicit `sourcing` going on, so BASH_SOURCE is not affected.

Instrument your shell scripts with

`declare -p BASH_SOURCE` lines to see the difference:

```
$ ./test.sh
declare -a BASH_SOURCE='([0]="common.sh" [1]="./test.sh")'
declare -a BASH_SOURCE='([0]="./test.sh")'
me: common.sh
```

vs:

```
$ ./test2.sh
declare -a BASH_SOURCE='([0]="./test2.sh")'
declare -a BASH_SOURCE='([0]="./test2.sh")'
me: test2.sh
```

In `test2.sh`, for all bash knows, you ran an arbitrary command, i.e. `$(echo ls)`.